# Reporte tres tablas anidadas

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Tengo las siguientes Tablas Anidadas, en SQL Server:

```
## Orden_Trabajo ##
ID   |   TITULO   |   FECHA_INICIO   |   FECHA_TERMINO    |   EQUIPO
---
1   |   FALLA MOTOR   |   1/12/17 8:00   |   2/12/17 12:00   |   100

## Tareas ##
ID   |   TAREA   |   FECHA_INICIO   |   FECHA_TERMINO
---
1   |   DESMONTAR MOTOR   |   1/12/17 8:00   |   1/12/17 12:00
2   |   REPARAR MOTOR   |   1/12/17 12:00   |   2/12/17 8:00
3   |   MONTAR MOTOR   |   2/12/17 8:00  |   2/12/17 12:00

## Tareas_Mecanicos ##
ID   |   TAREA   |   MECANICO
---
1   |   1   |   ABEL
2   |   1   |   BERNARDO
3   |   2   |   ABEL
4   |   2   |   CARLOS
5   |   2   |   DANIEL
6   |   2   |   EDUARDO
7   |   3   |   CARLOS
8   |   3   |   DANIEL
```

Estas tablas tienen su Clase Objeto en el sistema, necesito crear el siguiente reporte:

```
MANTENEDOR   |   TAREAS   |   SUMA DURACION
---
ABEL   |   1,2   |   24
BERNARDO   |   1   |   4
CARLOS   |   2,3   |   24
DANIEL   |   2,3   |   24
EDUARDO   |   2   |   20
```

Como puedo obtener una lista ***sin repeticiones*** de los Mantenedores y capturar a la vez las tareas donde participó.

Con un SELECT en la base de datos, o con listas ordenadas en sistema (C#)

Yo hice una Clase por cada tabla, y para el reporte cree una Lista ordenada:
***Clase OrdenTrabajo:***

```
public class OrdenTrabajo{
   public int IdOT;
   public string Titulo;
   public Datetime FechaInicio;
   public Datetime FechaTermino;
   public Equipo equipo;
}
```

***Clase Tarea:***

```
public class Tarea{
   public int IdTarea;
   public string tarea;
   public Datetime FechaInicio;
   public Datetime FechaTermino;
   public List<Mecanico> ListaMecanicos;

   public double GetDuracion(){
      TimeSpan ts = FechaTermino - FechaInicio;
      return ts.TotalHours;
   }
}
```

***Clase Mecanico:***

```
public class Mecanico{
   public int IdMecanico;
   public string NombreMecanico;
}
```

***Clase Turno:***

```
public class Turno {
    public Mecanico _Mecanico;
    public List<Tarea> _ListaTareas;

    public AgregarTarea(Tarea tarea){
      _ListaTareas.Add(tarea);
    }
}
```

Intento hacer el reporte utilizando una lista Turno y una lista de Mecanicos como pivote:

```
List<Turno> listaTurno = new List<Turno>();
List<Mecanico> listaMecanicos = new List<Mecanico>();
List<Tarea> tareas = GetListaTareasRangoFechas(fechaInicio,fechaTermino);
            for (int i = 0; i < tareas.Count; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < tareas[i].ListaMecanicos.Count; j++) {
                    if (!listaMantenedores.Contains(tareas[i].ListaMantenedores[j])) {
                        listaMecanicos.Add(tareas[i].ListaMecanicos[j]);
                        Turno turno = new Turno(tareas[i].ListaMecanicos[j]);
                        turno.AgregarTarea(tareas[i]);
                        listaTurno.Add(turno);
                    }else {
                        for (int k = 0; k < listaHHTurno.Count; k++) {
                            if(listaTurno[k]._Mecanico.IdMecanico == tareas[i].ListaMecanicos[j].IdMecanico) {
                                listaTurno[k].AgregarTarea(tareas[i]);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
```

Luego al imprimir la lista se repiten los ***Mecanicos***y solo tienen asignada una Tarea.

Answer (score 0):

Primero haría una columna para calcular las horas entre `FECHA_INICIO` y `FECHA_TERMINO`.

Una vez la tengas, puedes sacar lo que pides con algo del estilo:

```
SELECT MECANICO AS MANTENEDOR, TAREA AS TAREAS, SUM(NOMBRECOLUMNADURACION) AS SUMADURACION
FROM TAREAS_MECANICOS, TAREAS
WHERE TAREAS_MECANICOS.TAREA = TAREAS.ID
GROUP BY MANTENEDOR, TAREAS
```

Answer (score 0):

No sé usar C#, en sql se obtendría el mismo reporte de la siguiente manera:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS MANTENEDOR1
SELECT TAREA, MECANICO,'tarea' AS TAREAS,0 AS SUMA_DURACION ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MECANICO ORDER BY TAREA) AS ORDEN_M,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY MECANICO)  AS ORDEN_G
INTO MANTENEDOR1 FROM TAREAS_MECANICOS
DECLARE @TAREAS VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @DURACION DECIMAL(10,2)
DECLARE @COUNT1 INT
DECLARE @TCOUNT INT
    SET @TCOUNT=(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM MANTENEDOR1)
    SET @COUNT1=1
WHILE   @COUNT1<= @TCOUNT
BEGIN
    SET @TAREAS=(SELECT CASE WHEN ORDEN_M=1 THEN '' ELSE @TAREAS END FROM MANTENEDOR1 WHERE ORDEN_G=@COUNT1) 
    SET @DURACION=(SELECT CASE WHEN ORDEN_M=1 THEN 0 ELSE @DURACION END FROM MANTENEDOR1 WHERE ORDEN_G=@COUNT1)
    UPDATE MANTENEDOR1
    SET  TAREAS=a.TAREAS
    FROM (SELECT CONCAT(@TAREAS,a.TAREA) AS TAREAS  FROM MANTENEDOR1 a WHERE a.ORDEN_G=@COUNT1) a
    WHERE
    MANTENEDOR1.ORDEN_G=@COUNT1
    UPDATE MANTENEDOR1
    SET SUMA_DURACION=c.DURACION
    FROM (SELECT (datediff(hour,(a.Fecha_Inicio),(a.Fecha_Termino))+@DURACION) AS DURACION FROM TAREAS a INNER JOIN MANTENEDOR1 b ON a.ID=b.TAREA AND b.ORDEN_G=@COUNT1) c
    WHERE
    MANTENEDOR1.ORDEN_G=@COUNT1

    SET @TAREAS=(SELECT CONCAT(TAREA,', ') FROM MANTENEDOR1 WHERE ORDEN_G=@COUNT1)
    SET @DURACION=(SELECT datediff(hour,(a.Fecha_Inicio),(a.Fecha_Termino)) FROM TAREAS a INNER JOIN MANTENEDOR1 b ON a.ID=b.TAREA AND ORDEN_G=@COUNT1)

    SET @COUNT1=@COUNT1+1
END

SELECT a.MECANICO,a.TAREAS,a.SUMA_DURACION FROM  MANTENEDOR1 a,(
SELECT mecanico,max(orden_M) orden FROM MANTENEDOR1
group by MECANICO) b
where
a.MECANICO=b.MECANICO
and
a.ORDEN_M=b.orden
order by a.MECANICO
```

Genero una tabla de la que voy a extraer el reporte con dos indicadores de conteo uno me sirve para restablecer los indicadores y otra para seguir con la siguiente linea y actualice la tabla después solo le pido los máximos por mecánico.